# virtualenv on Windows, activate/deactivate events/hooks

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am working on Windows (sadface) with Python and virtualenv.

I would like to have *setup* and *teardown* scripts that go along with the virtualenv activation/deactivation. But I am not sure if these hooks have already been designated, and if so, where?

I guess I could hack the activate.bat, but then what if I use activate.py instead (does activate.py call activate.bat, or must I hack both files)? I can almost get away with environment variable PYTHONSTARTUP, but this needs to be redefined in each virtualenv. So unless virtualenv allows arbitrary assignment of env-vars, I am back to an activation/deactivation hook to set PYTHONSTARTUP (which really defeats the purpose, but now you see my catch-22).

EDIT: I plan to use my virtualenv to host interactive development sessions. I will be calling 'venv/bin/activate.bat' manually from the terminal. I do not want loose Batch/Powershell scripts laying around that I have to remember to call once when I activate, and once again when I deactive. I want to hook the execution in such a way, so that after I add my custom scripting hooks, 6 months later I don't have to remember how it works. I just execute `activate.bat`, and I am off to the races.

Comment: Why are you so opposed to modifying the bat/ps scripts to do this?  They are the setup/tear down scripts for the venv; it makes sense that anything you'd want to setup or tear down about a venv would go in them.  That's what I've always done when I needed to do something like this.

Comment: so, even when using `activate.py`, the bat scripts are executed? If so, then I would agree with your comment. I was trying to avoid BAT wrappers which make my adjustments and then also call activate.bat. Which bat script should be modified (activate.bat directly?). Please post a short answer describing your `venv/bin` contents and how you hooked in your custom scripts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many problems lessened or solved with virtualenvwrapper-win. Well written framework, with simple entry points.I spend a lot of time fighting with windows, trying to get a functional python work environment. This is one of the those programs I really wish I knew about a long time ago.

Does not handle multiple python installations extraordinarily (or switching between them), but the  project owner also developed another supporting product, `pywin`, meant to augment that particular shortcoming.

The whole point is, that it makes Windows command-line development quite a bit smoother, even if its not all the automation I dream about.